# gsutil streaming doesn't seem to actually stream

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

I'm following the instructions here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming

As I start a process to upload to Google Cloud Storage via streaming, the process has to complete before anything shows up in google cloud.  If the process gets interrupted in any way nothing ever shows up.

Is there a way to actually stream to gcloud storage (and perhaps even be able to start downloading before the upload is complete?

Answer (score 1):

It actually does do streaming via resumable uploads, but won't send a chunk until you've hit the resumable chunk size:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/88ab2023f0dcf3d7a5444832eb547b2cbc68d7bd/gslib/util.py#L833

You can write a fairly simple python script to generate more than that at a time, then pause, allowing you to see the uploads occurring:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(3):
  sys.stdout.write('a' * 1024 * 1024 * 101L)
  time.sleep(10)
```

And pipe it to gsutil like so:

```
python my_data_generator.py | gsutil cp - gs://BUCKET/OBJECT
```

to watch the data transfer for a while, stop at the sleep, and continue.

To reduce this chunk size, you can tweak the `GSUtil:json_resumable_chunk_size` option in your .boto file.